# Llamar una función desde un input

Tags: python

estaba pensando en un programa que hice hace tiempo, ese programa era basicamente un montón de `if`, `elif` y `else` que se repetían en un `while` y se y cada uno de esos `if` tenían como resultado llamar una función dependiendo de el input de el usuario, entonces se me ocurrió que todo sería más facil se es que pudiera hacer algo más parecido a esto:

```
def a():
    print("a")
def b():
    print("b")

while True:
    input("Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: ")
    #en esta parte algúna linea de codigo que llame a la función del input
```

en lugar de esto:

```
def a():
    print("a")
def b():
    print("b")

while True:
    var = input ("Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: ")
    if var == "a":
        a()
    elif var == "b":
        b()
```

Comment: para esos casos puedes usar eval() o exec(), pero ello es considerado una mala practica a nivel profesional ya que le das la capacidad al usuario a acceder a cualquier tipo de recursos.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo pones como respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
def a():
    print("a")
def b():
    print("b")
def salir():
    print("Programa terminado")
    quit()

func = { 'a':a, 'b':b, 'salir':salir }
while True:
    var = input("Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: ")
    if var in func:
        func[var]()
    else:
        print("Error: entraste un dato no valido")
```

Resultado

```
>>> Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: a
a
>>> Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: b
b
>>> Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: c
Error: entraste un dato no valido
>>> Ingresa el nombre de la función que quieres llamar: salir
Programa terminado
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementar las funciones en cuestión como métodos de una clase, y hacer otro método `ejecuta()` que haga "introspección" (mediante `getattr()`) para ver si un nombre dado es o no un método de la clase. Si lo es, lo ejecuta y si no por ejemplo retornamos `None`.

Incluso puedes hacer que el método "ejecuta" admita parámetros que pueda pasar al método que va a invocar, haciendo uso de los típicos `*args` y `**kwargs`.

Esta sería la idea:

```py
class Comandos:
  d = "No es una funcion"

  def a(self):
    print("Ejecutada a")
    return 0

  def b(self):
    print("Ejecutada b")
    return 1

  def c(self, dato=0):
    print("Ejecutada c con dato={}".format(dato))
    return dato*2

  def ejecuta(self, nombre, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      funcion = getattr(self, nombre)
    except AttributeError:
      funcion = None
    if callable(funcion):
      return funcion(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
>>> cmd = Comandos()
>>> cmd.ejecuta("a")
Ejecutada a
0
>>> cmd.ejecuta("c")
Ejecutada c con dato=0
0
>>> cmd.ejecuta("c", 20)
Ejecutada c con dato=20
40
>>> cmd.ejecuta("f")
# (no pasa nada porque "f" no es un atributo de la clase)
>>> cmd.ejecuta("d")
# (no pasa nada, porque "d" no es una función, aunque sea un atributo de la clase)
```